# Python - decrypting encrypted response from EBS-EDT SOAP service using private key

Tags: python, xml, encryption, soap

I am integrating with EBS-EDT SOAP which uses wsse. I can successfully send XML envelope and receive an encrypted response. As I am making use of custom python code I decide I would manually try to decrypt the response first before implementing the wrapper code.

Based on the spec the following happens

1. Encryption key is encrypted with the public key from the original request contained in **EncryptedKey** tag.
2. This stage needs to be decoded as its base64.
3. This encryption key is then used in an AES 128 encryption to decrypt the XML body content.

P.S I looked at this blog with code snippets(not in python) and the process seems the same as what I am doing (http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2013/12/consuming-ebs-edt-soap-service-from-wcf.html)

I wrote the following python code snippet to decode the encryption key, but keep getting an error **ValueError: Ciphertext with incorrect length (not 512 bytes)**. I am guessing it has to do with padding or that the certificate key use isn't correct, but unfortunately, the spec doesn't indicate what the padding would be and I have tried multiple key usages with no success.

My decryption code sample

```py
    import base64
    from Cryptodome.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5
    from Cryptodome.PublicKey import RSA
    from Cryptodome.Random import get_random_bytes
    
    private_key_pem = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
    MIIJQQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCCSswggknAgEAAoICAQCnRxiy/wmrjSfl
    wJuctXiXkLpsdyj3xshMV+auYh4c7QZsh37W0PNOnqu77hopiO5ZiXUW2uDp3SUG
    /hPpvbnnxfEovpgNOY8pRT63vq5JpJ7xHSQ6l/8JAPGFAEYhyhLmfUbAVO8mpVRr
    Lo8uvqg3wPAubrpO50sBrTe6AEHceOsb21L8maHvf2kPYS/LrSLmvWiiRePrlZgX
    d7M+Co0D3NxMDAUC1m1ryPqVDzZyBT1PbEDMkeyPXHgw0DxLQV3yIqVFWTuemTHE
    r23JsLZHc18OggQTBefABlQGwZ6jvIS/MfVGgmhdU3sJKWMMyuHNpLExNj2FG63r
    th/poewX3jwkthxteyRGQm+H7PD5nBzDgZokXy1dwH7dJ0bFe1lYWAXeEMuFlyvN
    ZoWHrdOHfLvZKxFRW0i3eQGV84wCzii5Qir+o+N6rYbAapOxWOlf+mZEcL0swEMN
    mL/xXL+JqGi7h5MiVCfoc+HMapczNxI88jdwd1+pPxFPIXCPuYciTdP1BHzYPwT6
    +5TEDT0pErnECI+2VTblgcHc6dHrFLFl80FFUbWrd5KXhtZjPhSJ3kxf4XCT0KLE
    qEjJpJYS4o/cgG9ICXRGVIiHHsULJz9UqZ6jK7ERQLvP9FAy0DeBdbZCmz3T4FRH
    Vfh1oGMpEPCReVWe7d2pPr9c7Jk4RwIDAQABAoICADbTGvnDlABJZcur6nScl5cZ
    ZLha/67h1FENODpsRxFU8BeO+xfd6PiaEZApFCML0Y6/+gPRHgkYJWQazxz7RVx8
    6DLh8MTY2h59JvajBM13Km69Ddw0Z+6kBASC1/mIGNS5N4Ce9bjVVAtC+cOo0kpf
    rniRavekX9V/V7XbErr3WJtLMXI/yi7MM/tJ75fSOY+lgY85198lKvF6FmGdpKUg
    9ITqJZROAhPjDZngIAiTxgnrYXuK0h0UggIBpdlGZcuP5loJynwLGqArnRCPHdbi
    LcP8AejYNSIfENgcCmoAxgNCFPEUma8Ixtj0WxXcwtAbC8Yk0Fn5ffG0wdXZb57E
    W4Ebwwk0xhIUG53KmiNM01Yc0O+RO7L7FJnU5+Ajv+lDF7uuMDHkSEZiRUWYHDNI
    BdHxJ6fzz3wwvM+bwlInUnw0Rd+VnTEtVlaQLN10DNAvt6YI6RL6WaH94W7DaALx
    3qO3ytnLAVX437hXWDbn5oWzUXkxhgj3o0WuTQJfPSA1tROr7nJiMYVlK6iOWgkQ
    Fe/MxjjjtrTbYcRAPA3sSRpGPdYrKM7IIYzJwuu0u951AYQgzm2CwEkFKB4BAqq8
    QWPk3yO2GUaxyUrxS2u4nIeI9dz3sPcpTEni4wKKfuNyV1SwCeUjgv+HQfOwlpQ3
    Tx3kUCh9I82XylKZuuoZAoIBAQC3Kt8A8gjiNTvsqWmuwGX0lcFdDJQgjXnZnux5
    4DBO16deSz4jrOeHUtzwk2rfdWPWTTGq32Z2ItSXytYtLKkS6c5u/ERt9XfdIFf5
    xeJsY13LlDmL2aHDSknt7lO/PZRzh7pk1StIYkShxKTVO5z/ADMZzVcp0kQSvmLl
    1GdRjBZr8VjKFZgggG2Zi8iNPRN3CYdAFNvIP5U88d/wZgIOEOddGu6zKua+wf/A
    Wb0kpzfRUAbhQwmshL1vfGGaGCIHSvdcfN2CP6CS5muJZdIu7lQbc3texeLJx64s
    dqvuDYy7mRxIGkBGgYBKLsg9dix5t/CvpWfFrHx2ZRcWOz4ZAoIBAQDpysOISpQt
    fJKKq89B6kJ9rjJVMO9877qJMhUYAHjG4+X24vP/yQNTjC1f9F3gLqDKQGlb3FrB
    Teh0cnMuS5dIML79/gZYXU6UH3KF/VlZumF/3HfVPqXmk2spWEX5xSxP+vANNG0l
    g5zSeybqTJKZtlr8weIb8IOiZWR1T3SOMmPMzFkm0GoFvZ3Bp8F/0INsHERCZfcB
    psTAbAucKa8ia5ID6Q+v9gQujuBIZnmi2DhEUqomGfQ5XsDkdnAAO/O3xNMj/oSp
    h9cIMifyneIOGypPtjOfcGgOkURiK2y0aorJwN2bR5qFRL8Fnsu0yiPJFuutdYs4
    LtqiZMrDEjVfAoIBAGdw452yEkhFjgD6L7/L0ghNpnS5DNJRc3Xt5VhyvnVYHqIG
    1iHpnJt0tWd7qUhnECnPUHRSU5f11Z+folLCvPz8Y2OUPcTncnjDsktRcKyLdUXq
    AJG1J0CVrKidBlijGzofdalKJXZsYJwG5JuzXdc4sqMorsfkgiMft9RZnruT5Hmz
    Q9RkW5RHUx36rhjtXBfGnsYWwYQWPF69rh0iTpjI/RA8jH9MhCFIh/mF9GZFtSUV
    D72ZUVZHZIAYezo91MHPmWB299V9v14WmLZwdUGhwIf8MLj2Ajy38uoTXsdCia7M
    KgeiI5htvBio0Na87SMUOO3I+JDO9z8Zme8pJ8kCggEAFYdheCR9/q5RBEoL/OLo
    mpA2/FdURmoBAG9HN/2bIZ2M6K4/j9df4gqvhv2Gw4Uns1g5G4dwKArXlBmR97po
    RPKQM+13gh2dhdBbiHErEDM0lUSlGFL7jf8XSChj0TtR+E+AWYbxYhn7j/pdPAgv
    G86KFGp6Ot5sEMFLfe4CKrIDNLHAp+1bRgoPA+1ByVZXM9Zqhr7C/zjvN1T7wLap
    9P545LlKg4ahHfR0PNaK7u8AR3JhTr7nGX1bP+6UI8FhkROj6dWfO8lRiOStfw8A
    6RGhVNPPbyg3vNett2iOSxLgkvGatpjiZtFM0eSsl4phvzvIGiIP3u2Znoivj0UW
    +wKCAQBrUZId08+FkLBZsKbLmj8SYosgtK68fmDRf41tcCRp0Q9U0wrKdMgeZTMg
    Agma41dv2oC+HuOAvRDBTeuwGJdqBfWKcznxMjhQbg5RGPvrj+PDbCZxzKy+rh8u
    wWhl2Gffk6FQHaJKhXHRov3KKiF2G9znRSCrRF0SLpTh4TeV+Rn0ecd4Vko9q6jF
    3EZqgHYugrB5EIaFlbrhRRvprFexMxViyxE3YaeUBDF5ieOKQa35MJZ8SJlp/iS7
    XzXJ7h20KoY3oRHljbBSffEtGe/djfWafgloHXDETs+QnkCY96Um/DXEV59CkHXx
    PURtfoyDKlUpHmoJ+ruyu0bHpE4W
    -----END PRIVATE KEY-----"
    
    s = "gJvJjWEsmTcGzDvmYhVsheWR234xfo6lXx+cJCsTTy6tUwSBR+l5qqEFVpGohiSJhwa5IsRBDiJ28dOOnz0T6J3MSq82q34R0n8hJ80Hz37HL4KlVsygcdGceDbSYsIrPQRrMKTc2HB79r8/CqnQw2K5e71Gkw44soEtyzeldQ5hQFtsGkM1jkA40Xdu7mAjzUQ1REAVvR1fb0nLi6LRPZq+wnfMajLy1+8y+pCcQpsFBA5BD8j8EgHCLnpQE6GiRE6CLQNOa3s8/bnF1iGDfpJzAT8qJWZVpfQ4SuAhS6HRLe/TpXe5cDXnbWZxtkjMggAvkhR18bVXC8F0Pg81lQ=="
    
    code_bytes = s.encode('UTF-8')
    print(s)
    print(code_bytes)
    by =  base64.b64decode(code_bytes)
    print(by)
    print(len(by))
    private_key = RSA.import_key(private_key_pem)
    cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(private_key)
    sentinel = get_random_bytes(16)
    #rsadecrypt = cipher.decrypt(by[3: 3 + 256], sentinel)
    rsadecrypt = cipher.decrypt(by, sentinel)
    if rsadecrypt == sentinel:
        print('failure')
    else:
        print(f'success: {rsadecrypt.hex(" ")}')
```

For completeness here is the commands I use to generate the server keys used for xml encryption.

````
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -extfile x509.ext -extensions ca -in CA.csr -signkey CA.key -days 1095 -out CA.pem
openssl req -new -sha256 -nodes -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout ohip.key -out ohip.csr
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -CA CA.pem -CAkey CA.key -days 730 -CAcreateserial -CAserial CA.srl -extfile x509.ext -extensions server -in ohip.csr -out ohip_crt.pem```
````

Comment: For RSA, the ciphertext size is equal to the key size. In the posted example, the key is 4096 bits (512 bytes), but the (Base64 decoded) ciphertext is only 256 bytes. Hence the error message.

Comment: I re-created the key with 2048 to match the 256 bytes. Basically then it returns the sentinel, which means it could not be decrypted. Leaving met to think that the server SOAP system isn't encrypting this message with my public key.

Answer (score 0):

The issue originated in the submission XML signing and encryption process. I was signing the XML tags with my private key and adding the  tag which is correct. However, in the following step, I would encrypt the entire XML envelope with their public key which also added a  tag. This caused the situation where the server would grab the wrong  tag and encrypt the AES key with their public key.